# Jest encountered an unexpected token when I run the npm run test

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Good day. I create a app using react and add the library of @testing-library/react. I also install use-global-hook and I was having an error when I run the npm run test. anyone could help me to get out to this error. Thanks

here's my pakage.json.
[package.json][1]

```
{
  "name": "trial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "use-global-hook": "^0.1.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.9.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

here's the error details

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Details:

    E:\Backups\Projects\React\trial\node_modules\use-global-hook\index.js:60
    export default useStore;
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import globalHook from 'use-global-hook';
        | ^
      3 | import actions from './actions';
      4 | import initState from './initState';
      5 | 

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/services/useGLobal.js:2:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `use-global-hook` repo. It seems that this package is distributed in ES Module. You will need to set up transformer for Jest so it understands ES module syntax.

[This is the documentation for Jest transform config](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object)